# What is the cost and benefit of building two identical telescopes?

Tags: telescope, space-telescope

I suppose that (especially space) telescope costs is dominated by design and development, not by material and manufacturing. So once a telescope has been developed and designed, how much extra would it cost to build a second copy of it? It seems as if spy satellites are built in batches of similar designs.

Would the science value of a second similar telescope be modest, compared to a unique instrument, or improvements on the single telescope, for the same cost?

I suppose that using two telescopes as an interferometer would be quite a different instrument design to begin with than just two of the same.

Comment: Not an answer, but related:   http://www.atlasobscura.com/places/large-binocular-telescope

Comment: It depends if there are any limitations on the observational parameters of the first, that a second one could lift. Simple example: The HARPS instrument can only observe on the southern hemisphere, so HARPS-North was built. Otherwise it would be hard to justify against just observing longer with only one scope/instrument.

Comment: @userLTK "Today the telescope is busy taking **stereoscopic** images of spiral galaxies, the crab nebula..." It isn't really doing that is it? If so I'd expect Brian May to be all over it! I'd asked [What are the raisons d'être for the Large Binocular Telescope “binocularity”?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/24163/7982) earlier because I don't really understand the choice of that configuration.

Comment: Well, with two identical telescopes, even sitting next to each other, you can observe two objects at the same time, so twice as many observation programs…